# GStreamer and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, gstreamer

I'm trying to add GStreamer to an existing project written in Swift. I have downloaded the tutorials which are in Objective-C. I have added the file I need into the bridging header, matched all the header search paths, framework search paths,  and  and linked all of library binaries that are in the example project.

However, I am unable to locate or add the GStreamer.framework

[image]

The GStreamer code is included in the project when it compiles, I know this because it triggers an enormous amount syntax warnings.

However, the code in the one class I added from the tutorials throws the error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_gst_version_string", referenced from:
      -[GStreamerBackend getGStreamerVersion] in GStreamerBackend.o
  "_g_free", referenced from:
      -[GStreamerBackend getGStreamerVersion] in GStreamerBackend.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Any success? I'm looking to do the same.

Comment: I ended up not using GStreamer

Comment: And used what instead?

Comment: We went with WebRTC

Comment: Aren't obj-c and swift interoperable? Couldn't you have proceeded that way?

Comment: That is what I was doing, using Obj-C and Swift together (see above, Bridging Header). However, the Framework was missing.

Answer (score 0):

try to add as Embedded Binaries.